# Mixed effect model covariance prior

Tags: mixed-model, random-effects-model, hierarchical-bayesian, singular-matrix

How should I choose the covariance prior for my bglmer model?

This is a model which has the singularity problem.

```
mod <- Y ~ X*Condition + (X*Condition|subject)

# Y = logit variable  
# X = continuous variable  
# Condition = values A and B, dummy coded; the design is repeated 
#             so all participants go through both Conditions  
# subject = random effects for different subjects 

summary(model)
Random effects:
 Groups  Name             Variance Std.Dev. Corr             
 subject (Intercept)      0.85052  0.9222                    
         X                0.08427  0.2903   -1.00            
         ConditionB       0.54367  0.7373   -0.37  0.37      
         X:ConditionB     0.14812  0.3849    0.26 -0.26 -0.56
Number of obs: 39401, groups:  subject, 219

Fixed effects:
                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)       2.49686    0.06909   36.14  < 2e-16 ***
X                -1.03854    0.03812  -27.24  < 2e-16 ***
ConditionB       -0.19707    0.06382   -3.09  0.00202 ** 
X:ConditionB      0.22809    0.05356    4.26 2.06e-05 ***
```

I would like to use the `blme` package to run the model with a cov. prior. However, there are multiple options to choose from, e.g. `wishart`, `invwishart`, `gamma` and `invgamma`.

1. What should guide my choice of cov.prior?
2. Is it appropriate to use the `rePCA` function to check for singularity, i.e. overfitting in `bglmer` models?
3. Is it appropriate to use the likelihood ratio test with `anova` function to reduce the overfitted `bglmer` models?